# How to deny access to shared folder from a specific user on Linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scp

i have 3 machines on my virtual box, Server, Host 1 and Host 2
i shared a directory from the server to both the hosts using the scp command
but now i need to deny the access to the shared folder from host 2 but keep it accessible to host 1, how do i do that please ?

Comment: Your setup does not make sense and this is likely an XY question. SCP is a file transfer mechanism on top of SSH, not a directory sharing protocol.  (specifically it does not know of shares, only of files it can access - typically based on filesyst permissions.)  Ypu may be able do do something with group/ownership permissions on the server and/or use IP address permissions - but is scp even appropriate compared with NFS?

Comment: @davidgo this is the question i was given: 
5. Make sure all three machines have connections to each other and they reply to ping echo requests from each other.
6. Use a firewall to control the network traffic as per the following requirements:
a. Deny ping traffic between Host2 and the Server.
b. Allow ping traffic between Host1 and the Server.
c. At the Server, share a directory which has a text file and give the permission for anyone to read it. Test the access to the shares from both hosts.
d. Deny access traffic from Host2 to the share and keep it allowed from Host1.

Comment: We dont do homework questions, and whoever set that one does is not competent in the real world. (...deny icmp traffic...). That said, it looks like you are being asked to block port 22 access on host 2.

Comment: Also, question does not mention SCP. Again, scp is not a file sharing protocol (its a file TRANSFER protocol that sits on ssh).  NFS and SMB are file sharing protocols.

Comment: @davidgo not sure if what I did is correct, but I used ssh to share a folder from the server to the hosts, and then changed the file permission using chmod on host 2. I've been searching for a better solution but couldn't find any. I think the assignment was explained poorly, anyways thank you for your help and time!! :)

Comment: Again, there is no such thing as using scp to share a folder - it is not a file sharing protocol.   Per the man page "scp copies files between hosts on a network." and " uses the same authentication and provides the same security as a login session. "  In other words, if the ssh user has access to /etc, scp will happily copy files in /etc.  Controlling permissions on host2, where host2 is the client is like letting the prisoners control access to the prison.  Unless there is something in the assignment not mentioned above, you really should use NFS for file sharing.